# Jquery timer runs only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on some js/jQuery but i've ran in to a problem.

There is a timer that should execute a function every x seconds. The problem, however, is that the timer seems to execute only once. I've asked some friends but they also didn't know what was wrong.

So if someone has a clue, please!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var id = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var obj;

    console.log(id);

    function getTweetsWithQuery(q) {
        console.log('getTweetsWithQuery did run');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "q=" + q,
            success: function(msg){

                obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                start();
            }
        });
        console.log('getTweetsWithQuery finished');
    }

    function updateTweets(obj) {

       var count = 0;

       $('#tweet' + id).animate({opacity: 0}, 1).delay(500);
       $('#tweet' + id).text(obj[count].text);
       $('#tweet' + id).delay(500).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);

       console.log(obj[count].text);
       console.log('updateTweets did run');

       if(id == 9){
        id = 0;
       }else {
        id++;
       }

       if(count == obj.length){
        count = 0;
       }else {
        count++;
       }



       console.log('Next id: ' + id);
       console.log('Next count: ' + count);


   }

   function start() {

    console.log('start did run')

    var timer = $.timer( updateTweets(obj) );

    timer.set( { time : 500, autostart : true } );

   }
 </script>
```

The getTweetsWithQuery() function gets called from within the html.

Comment: Do you have the `.timer` plugin included?  I don't think you need it since `setInterval` should be more then enough in this case.

Comment: the time plugin is included. I've also used setInterval, as Rory McCrossan described, but this had the same result

Comment: which timer plugin is it? I am having trouble tracking it down.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the function, not assigning a reference to it.

```
var timer = $.timer( function(){ updateTweets(obj); } );
```

Comment: with this answer, the function doesn't get called even once

Answer (score 0):

ok it is not ideal but I think this may work:

```
function start() {

    console.log('start did run')

    var timer = $.timer( function(){
        ar count = 0;

        $('#tweet' + id).animate({opacity: 0}, 1).delay(500);
        $('#tweet' + id).text(obj[count].text);
        $('#tweet' + id).delay(500).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);

        console.log(obj[count].text);
        console.log('updateTweets did run');

        if(id == 9){
           id = 0;
        }else {
           id++;
        }

        if(count == obj.length){
           count = 0;
        }else {
           count++;
        }

        console.log('Next id: ' + id);
        console.log('Next count: ' + count);
    });

    timer.set( { time : 500, autostart : true } );

   }
```

From what I have seen in the source for that plugin, it appears to have a problem with function objects. I am not sure why and I am not skilled enough to digest the source and figure out what is happening, but it does appear to work if you pass in a function definition.

here is a fiddle showing what you have and how I was able to get it to work.